# unable to install python module

Tags: python, paramiko

Unable to install Python module on Ubuntu machine. When I try to install the Paramiko module, I receive the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pip", line 5, in <module>
    from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py",  line 70, in <module>
    import packaging.version
ImportError: No module named packaging.version
```

Comment: What version of Python are you using? I assume you're trying to install it using pip also, yes?

Answer (score 3):

Finally I found a solution, it worked after cleaning up and re-installing pip:

```
sudo -i
apt-get purge -y python-pip
wget https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py
python ./get-pip.py
apt-get install python-pip
```

Comment: Does this endanger my previous pip / python installations? Does the reinstalled pip recognize the already installed pip packages?

Answer (score 0):

Run

```
pip install packaging
```

Add `sudo` if it is nessesary. It must resolve the issue.

Comment: When I try to install packagin module, again receiving same error

Answer (score 0):

there might be a problem with your pip installation try:

```
sudo pip install --upgrade pip
```